# Customizable model file for a Laravel 5 package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a Laravel 5 package where I have a **"Member" model** which currently **extends App\User** model. I would like to know the **best practice** to let any developer use a **custom** "Member" **model** instead of the one from the package. This is for example to allow a developer use another table.

One approach that seems to work without having done a deep test with it is to make an alias in my package service provider in the register() method:

```
$MemberModel = 'MyVendor\MyPackage\Member';
$loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
$loader->alias('MyMember', $MemberModel);
```

In this case I have to:

- Replace all entries in the code from the original class to the alias
- Delete all php "use" entries related to it
- Get the value of $MemberModel from a config file or the database

But I don't know if it is a good way to solve it or It may cause any conflict.

Is there any other and better approach for this goal? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally had to test by myself this approach without haven't read the solution anywhere else, but anyway everything seems to work fine in my source code.

If anyone is looking for doing anything similar, the code example in my question works because the **$MemberModel** is defined with a value. If you want to get that value **from a Model instance**, as me, you have to add that code in the **boot()** method of the service provider.